# List count method in if condition of python

Tags: python, list

The following code doesn't work properly, I want it to make a list to a new list with no element appears more than twice. For instance, modify `l = [3, 3, 3, 5, 9]` to `[3, 3, 5, 9]`. Here is my code:

```
l = [3, 3, 3, 5, 9]
bl = []

for i in l:
    if l.count(i) > 2:
        l.remove(i)
    else:
        bl.append(i)
print(l)
print(bl)
```

Its output:

> [3, 3, 5, 9] 
>   [3, 5, 9]

The list `l` is correctly modified while the new list `bl` is not as I expected. I think it's wrong at my `if`-statement.

Comment: you are modifiying your list while iterating over it, you should not do that.

Comment: never remove items on the list you are iterating over (unless you **really** know what you are doing)!

Answer (score 2):

You are modifiyint your list while iterating over it, create a copy to solve it:

```
l = [3,3,3,5,9]
bl = []

for i in l[::]:
    if l.count(i) > 2:
        l.remove(i)
    else:
        bl.append(i)
print(l)
print(bl)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ToughVainQuote)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not care about how many times the current element is in the source list, but if it's already two times in the target list or not:

```
l = [3,3,3,5,9]
bl = []

for i in l:
    if bl.count(i) < 2:
        bl.append(i)
print(l)
print(bl)

#[3, 3, 3, 5, 9]
#[3, 3, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
l = [3,3,3,5,9]

c = Counter(l)
l_new = [k for k,v in c.items() for _ in range(min(v,2))]

#[3, 3, 5, 9]
```

Note that by using `count()` for each element in the list you end up with a `O(n**2)`  solution for something that can be done in linear time.
This is why I'm using a counter here.